# Expandable/collapable layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Please i need a way to design an expandable layout that change its hieght and elements position and state(GONE,VISIBLE) with an animation just like the pictures below

[Medium height](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F6EPr8onnhE8clAm87N1RZhRg5yoIi9K/view?usp=drivesdk)

[Minimum heght](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_uLwZ5NPuLJJ7W5c1qISgCs6yZOFgjH7/view?usp=drivesdk)

[Full height (match_parent)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OanQF0bPPQd3dQFM28XOBF-x2S_yiHLn/view?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `animateChanges = "true"` in the parent layout of the views. The animation will be taken care by the android itself

Comment: And how to change the height and add elements by scrolling up and down

Comment: why do you want to change the height?? You can keep two seperate views and on scroll you can switch the views according to your need.